# How to sort single table inheritance(STI) models by each count method?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There are Project model and ProjectGroup model, and ProjectGroup model inherit form Project model.

```
# Project
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :child_projects
end

# ProjectGroup inherit Project
class ProjectGroup < Project
   has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
   has_and_belongs_to_many :docs
   # ProjectGroup is Project.where(:type => ''ProjectGroup)
end
```

Project model has_and_belongs_to_many docs, and I want to order Project model and ProjectGroup(as Project.where(:type => 'ProjectGroup')) by count of docs

Count of docs for Project model is the number of docs related to the project, on the other hand, count of docs for ProjectGroup model is amount of docs related to all the projects which related to a ProjectGroup.

I wrote scope to order by docs count for each model, and those differ only in the joins condition.
I know that the joins method is too complex, so you can ignore these methods if it bother you.

```
# Project  model
scope :order_pmdocs_count, 
joins("
LEFT OUTER JOIN projects_sprojects ON projects_sprojects.sproject_id = projects.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN docs_projects ON docs_projects.project_id IN (projects_sprojects.project_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN docs ON docs.id = docs_projects.doc_id AND docs.sourcedb = 'PubMed'
").group('projects.id').order("count(docs.id) DESC")

# ProjectGroup  model   
scope :order_docs_count, 
joins("
LEFT OUTER JOIN projects_sprojects ON projects_sprojects.sproject_id = projects.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN docs_projects ON docs_projects.project_id IN (projects_sprojects.project_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN docs ON docs.id = docs_projects.doc_id AND docs.sourcedb = 'PubMed'
").group('projects.id').order("count(docs.id) DESC")
```

Is it possible to switch or mix these join method and order Project model and ProjectGroup model(as Project model) by count of docs?　
Or is there another way to order these models by each count method?